# Removing grout from tile pores

Tags: grout

What's the best way to remove grout from the tiny pores in backsplash tiles? I tried grout haze remover and distilled white vinegar without much success. I am not sure if there is a certain amount of time I should leave the vinegar on the tiles before wiping off with water. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is  it travertine?  Some of the porous natural stones need to be sealed before grouting

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A close-up picture of the problem area would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of tile, muriatic acid might do it.  Recommended to test on an inconspicuous area.  Follow instructions and proper safety procedures.  A less dangerous and more tedious way would be to use a dental pick to remove it.

Comment: I used a toothbrush with the bristles cut short on our kitchen tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Vinegar has a hard enough time removing just haze. Actual grout; good luck.

Tiles with holes in them are supposed to be filled with grout, and are usually floors, not backslashes. You should have chosen a grout color better suited to porous tile; which is always an option, especially if you want darker (which is always the way to go, imo).

Answer (score 0):

We've had this problem for several weeks now after someone's sloppy job retiling our bathroom floor (stone tiles).

Today by chance my SO tried scrubbing with Mr. Clean MagicEraser (I have no affiliation whatsoever), and wow. With enough force it got there, totally clean now.

Not sure if it will work for all cases, so try a small area first. Maybe it only worked for us because our stone tiles were white and light grey-blues.

Was so happy I came here to ask just to self-answer and share, was happy to find your question to answer.